# How to show top 10 with most views?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to show the top 10 seeded torrents on my website but according to hits(views) & date added.

Here's code that i'm using this code shows top 10 most seeded torrents. But i want to show top 10 most seeded torrents of last 24hrs. After 24hrs of torrent uploaded.It should be replaced by next most seeded torrent of last 24hrs.

```
$movie = "
SELECT t.id
     , t.anon
     , t.announce
     , t.category
     , t.leechers
     , t.nfo
     , t.seeders
     , t.name
     , t.times_completed
     , t.size
     , t.added
     , t.comments
     , t.numfiles
     , t.filename
     , t.owner
     , t.external
     , t.freeleech
     , c.name AS cat_name
     , c.image AS cat_pic
     , c.parent_cat AS cat_parent
     , u.username
     , u.privacy
     , IF(t.numratings < 2, NULL, ROUND(t.ratingsum / t.numratings,1)) rating
  FROM torrents t
  LEFT 
  JOIN categories c
    ON c.id = t.category 
  LEFT 
  JOIN users u
    ON u.id = t.owner
 WHERE visible = 'yes' 
   AND banned = 'no' 
   AND c.parent_cat = 'Movie'  
 ORDER 
    BY t.seeders + t.leechers + t.hits DESC
     , t.seeders DESC
     , t.added DESC 
 LIMIT 10
";
```

Please solve this i'm trying to solve this from last Month. Or If possible Torrent with most views from last 24hrs should be shown on top.

Comment: To which table do `visible` and `banned` belong. If `user` then you need to move those conditions to the ON clause (or dispense with the LEFT [OUTER] JOIN)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whats your torrent tables schema ?

is torrents.added DATETIME column or just regular INT for unix timestamps ?

```
$movie = "
SELECT t.id
     , t.anon
     , t.announce
     , t.category
     , t.leechers
     , t.nfo
     , t.seeders
     , t.name
     , t.times_completed
     , t.size
     , t.added
     , t.comments
     , t.numfiles
     , t.filename
     , t.owner
     , t.external
     , t.freeleech
     , c.name AS cat_name
     , c.image AS cat_pic
     , c.parent_cat AS cat_parent
     , u.username
     , u.privacy
     , IF(t.numratings < 2, NULL, ROUND(t.ratingsum / t.numratings,1)) rating
  FROM torrents t
  LEFT 
  JOIN categories c
    ON c.id = t.category 
  LEFT 
  JOIN users u
    ON u.id = t.owner
 WHERE visible = 'yes' 
   AND banned = 'no' 
   AND c.parent_cat = 'Movie'  
   AND t.added > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
 ORDER 
    BY t.seeders + t.leechers + t.hits DESC
     , t.seeders DESC
     , t.added DESC 
 LIMIT 10
";
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add to the `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE visible = 'yes' AND banned = 'no' 
AND categories.parent_cat= 'Movie'
AND torrents.uploaded_date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

Comment: I added the above with my code but now it shows, Database Error!
Where should i added the comment you just give?

Comment: @user3541450 Did you change the `torrents.uploaded_date` to match your date column name? It should replace your current `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Yeap i tried now changing it
{WHERE visible = 'yes' AND banned = 'no' 
AND categories.parent_cat= 'Movie'
AND torrents.added > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)}
Like that didn't work.

Comment: @user3541450 In what way didn't it work? Did you get an error? If so what was it?

Comment: @user3541450 The code that is showing "Database Error" should check `mysqli_error` (if you're using mysqli) this will provide a more helpful message.

Comment: i used WHERE visible = 'yes' AND banned = 'no' 
AND categories.parent_cat= 'Movie'
AND torrents.added > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
After adding that it started showing database Error I'm using Mysql

Comment: you can take example of extratorrent.cc
please check this when i use the code i posted it will show the Torrent.
But when i add the code you provide it gives error
http://timetorrent.org/a.php

Comment: @user3541450 I can't be of much use without a clearer error message. You'll need to find the code that is displaying "Database error" and get this to either display a more appropriate error or log the error somewhere (if it isn't already).